# Can the time interval between measurements A and B be arbitrarely small?

Tags: quantum-spin, particle-detectors, pair-production

If we make two measuraments of a particle-antiparticle spin should the interval between the two measuraments be so small that no signal emitted by one particle can have effect on the measueament of the other particle if both paths X/2 are equal in length? Of course, the distance between detectors A and B should be long enough....[image]

Comment: What do you mean "should"? Do you mean that in order to do a good experiment you need timing close enough to rule out lightspeed or slower signals between the particles, or do you mean that you think there is some limit on the time interval between the measurements? (In the later case I think the answer is no since relativity makes simultaneity moot anyway).

Comment: @AndersSandberg You know about 'spooky action at the distance' where they argue there should be a speed of communication between entangled particles so if there is that speed the signal should travel for a while between the two particles at A and B...but if we make the time interval short enough the signal cannot affect the other particle before it is measured.....